# Npm run build does not show fonts, Vite

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, vue.js

I am compiling my project with 'npm run build', and then I use the 'npm run preview' command to visualize it. But it does not show some images that I set as a background images in my SCSS file. The same happens with a font family.

This is my 'package.json' file:

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.52.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  }
}
```

And this is my 'vite.config.js' file:

```
/* Do not edit this file */
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        minify: false
    }
});
```

This is my scss. It seems when compiling Vite does not understand the'../../../ directory:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "CustomFont";
    src: url("../../../src/assets/fonts/Marcheile-Bold-Condensed.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../../../src/assets/fonts/Marcheile-Bold-Condensed.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("../../../src/assets/fonts/Marcheile-Bold-Condensed.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

Comment: `does not show some images that I set as a background images` so, some background imaegs do show and others do not?

Comment: yes, some images are showing and others don´t

Comment: But mainly is not showing those which are set as a background image in scss.

Answer (score 0):

Your assets should be in the same directory as the code. I assume it's `dist` directory according to your `vite.config.js`

Try to define `publicDir` https://v2.vitejs.dev/config/#publicdir

> Directory to serve as plain static assets. Files in this directory are served at / during dev and copied to the root of outDir during build, and are always served or copied as-is without transform. The value can be either an absolute file system path or a path relative to project root.

Then change the `url` in your `scss` (remove "../../.." or something like that)

Look in the `dist` directory for answers

Comment: Hello Kurama, I managed to solve this by getting the images out of the assets folder and I put them in the root directory, next to the 'index.html' and 'package.json' files. I guess this is the root or public directory, right?. Then I removed "../../..". After that I ran the build and everything was placed again in the assets folder but it was perfect after running 'npm run preview'. Is this what you were trying to suggest?